# MySQL pivot in same table

Tags: mysql, database, pivot

> MySQL pivot in same table with dynamic content

**Create Table Code**

```
CREATE TABLE `product_table` (
    `id` INT(10) NOT NULL,
    `pdate` DATE NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `product` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    `counts` VARCHAR(50) NULL DEFAULT NULL,
    PRIMARY KEY (`id`)
)
COLLATE='utf8_general_ci'
ENGINE=InnoDB;
```

**I have table structure as below**

```
+----+------------+---------+--------+
| id |   pdate    | product | counts |
+----+------------+---------+--------+
|  1 | 2015-10-12 | BOX     |     74 |
|  2 | 2015-10-12 | SHOE    |     35 |
|  3 | 2015-10-12 | PEN     |     38 |
|  4 | 2015-10-12 | WATCH   |     36 |
|  5 | 2015-10-13 | BOX     |     36 |
|  6 | 2015-10-13 | SHOE    |     80 |
|  7 | 2015-10-13 | PEN     |     70 |
|  8 | 2015-10-13 | WATCH   |     73 |
+----+------------+---------+--------+
```

**I would like to have report as this format**

```
+---------+------------+------------+
| product | 2015-10-12 | 2015-10-13 |
+---------+------------+------------+
| BOX     |         74 |         36 |
| SHOE    |         35 |         80 |
| PEN     |         38 |         70 |
| WATCH   |         36 |         73 |
+---------+------------+------------+
```

what i tried so far

```
select 
    d.p product,
    (select date(p.pdate) from product_table p where date(p.pdate)=d.dt and p.product = d.p ) date,
    (select p.counts from product_table p where date(p.pdate)=d.dt and p.product = d.p ) cnt
from
(select pt.product p,date(pt.pdate) dt from product_table pt group by pt.product,date(pt.pdate) ) as d
group by product
```

Comment: are the dates argument or will you get them from the table

Comment: @BerndBuffen will get from table

Comment: so it can many field, for each date 1 ?

Comment: @BerndBuffen couldn't get you

Comment: Google:  "mysql dynamic pivot".

Comment: i have edit my answer to your fieldnames

Comment: Have a look at this article - [Pivot Tables in MySQL](https://codingsight.com/pivot-tables-in-mysql/)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately MySQL does not have implemented table pivoting. So there is workaround with building a dynamic query, here is my example:

```
SELECT 
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(
     CONCAT(
        'MAX(
            IF(pt.pdate =  \'', pdate, '\', pt.counts, null)
         ) AS \'' , pdate, '\''
     )
   )
) INTO @dates FROM product_table;

SET @query = CONCAT('SELECT product, ', @dates, ' FROM product_table pt   GROUP BY product');

PREPARE stmt FROM @query;
EXECUTE stmt;
```

Please note that if you have a lot of dates in your table it may be very slow

Comment: it works flawless, is it possible to excecute using jstl and jsp

Comment: Unfortunately I've never worked with jstl nor jsp, so I can't answer on your question. BTW you marked wrong answer as correct :)

Answer (score 0):

please try this:
remove the remark to see the Query

```
 SELECT DISTINCT
  CONCAT(   'SELECT p.product  ',
  GROUP_CONCAT( 
  CONCAT(   ',SUM( IF(pdate = \'', pdate,'\', p.count,0)) as \'', pdate,'\'') SEPARATOR '\n'),
  ' FROM product_table p GROUP BY p.product;') INTO @sql FROM product_table p;

-- SELECT @sql;
PREPARE stmt FROM @sql;
EXECUTE stmt;
DEALLOCATE PREPARE stmt;
```