# Create Pivot In h2

Tags: h2

I have a view in Oracle that uses `PIVOT` and I would like to apply it to an h2 database. However, Pivot is not yet supported in h2.

I am currently using `CASE` statements to do the pivot which is fine for now.

However, I am intrigued by user defined functions in h2.

Is it possible to create a generic `PIVOT` function in h2 by using user defined functions? Has anyone already done it?

Answer (score 0):

Oracle and SQL Server are the only popular databases to have a `PIVOT` (or `UNPIVOT`) clause, which generates several aggregate columns for input rows.

In all other databases, you'll have to resort to do manual pivoting, the way you did.

Stack Overflow is full of such questions for MySQL, for instance:

- [MySQL pivot table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7674786/mysql-pivot-table)
- [MySQL pivot in same table](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33101722/mysql-pivot-in-same-table)
- [MySQL pivot query](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16668101/mysql-pivot-query)
- [MySQL Pivot or Excel Solution](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14783414/mysql-pivot-or-excel-solution)

Comment: h2 has user defined functions though. e.g. I have made Oracles TO_DATE function available in h2 this way. I'm wondering how far the functions can go.

Comment: @opticyclic: Yes, but `PIVOT` is not a scalar function. It transforms tables just like `GROUP BY` does. I doubt that this is possible in H2. If you want to be sure, I suggest asking this question on the [h2 user group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!forum/h2-database)